Sharing google calendar to a person that is not in organization
I need to share google calendars that belong to admin accout to some personal accounts. But when I try I can only share it to watch, not to edit.
In the same time, I can give permission to edit to corporative accounts.
How can I change it? Is there any way?
Already tried to surf admin.google.com. But found only permission settings for apps, not third party account

In the calendar settings there should be a section called "Access permissions for events" and another called "Share with specific people or groups":

You should be able to set the access permissions so that all the event details are available to anyone in your org without making them public to the entire world.
If you aren't in a formal Google organization, go to "Share with specific people or groups" and add the people/groups. You'll be able to define which permissions each person or group have and what's visible to them.

